# Split time recording method for tasks in Project Server

Tags: project-team, task-management, project-server

We would like to separate % Work Complete, Work, Remaining Work, Actual work in the task updates on Project Server. For example, a resource is allocated to work 8 hours on a task. The resource records 50 % Work complete, but the remaining work should not automatically update, therefore allowing the resource to record two hours remaining work even though there may be 4 hours remaining.

Is this possible in Project Server 2013?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this a few times and the only solution that's satisfied my needs is to break the task into smaller tasks. In your example, you'd edit the 8-hour task by breaking it up:

- (1) 4-hour task, 100% complete
- (1) 4-hour task, 0% complete